# Как вывести имя текстового файла и его содержание? C#

Tags: c#

Предположим, что у нас есть 3 текстовых файла, которые будут называться, на пример, one.txt, two.txt и three.txt. В файле one.txt написано число 100. В файле two.txt - 15. И в three.txt - 60
Как мне вывести имена этих файлов (можно и вместе с .txt) и их содержимое в таком формате:

```
one.txt - 100
two.txt - 15
three.txt - 60
```

Нашел код, но он выводит только содержимое файлов, никак не могу сделать так, чтобы вместе с этим содержимым выводилось имя файла, в котором оно находится

```
var fileStorage = new List<string[]>();
string path = @"..."
                        string[] promoDir = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                        try
                        {
                            var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path); //string[]
                            foreach (string path in filePaths)
                            {
                                string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
                                fileStorage.Add(fileLines);
                            }
                            foreach (string[] fileLines in fileStorage)
                            {
                                foreach (string fileLine in fileLines)
                                {
                                            Console.WriteLine();                                           
                                }
                            }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое элементарное:

```
var result = Directory.GetFiles("temp")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(x),
                    Value = File.ReadAllText(x)
                });
```

Вывод:

```
foreach (var file in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{file.Name} - {file.Value}");
```

---

Пояснения:

- `Directory.GetFiles("temp")` - Получаем файлы указанной директории (в моем случае это `temp`, которая лежит рядом с .exe файлом проекта).
- `.Select()` - одно из расширений LINQ, которое каждый элемент коллекции переводит в нужный нам вид. В моем случае это анонимный тип с двумя значениями (`Name` и `Value`).
- `Name = Path.GetFileName(x)` - В `Name` мы помещаем имя файла с расширением (если надо без него, то используем `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`).
- `Value = File.ReadAllText(x)` - в `Value` помещаем весь текст из файла.

Тут можно играться как вам угодно, например делаем сразу `String` с нужным видом:

```
var result = Directory.GetFiles("temp")
    .Select(x => $"{Path.GetFileName(x)} - {File.ReadAllText(x)}" );
```

Тут уже смотрите сами что вам нужно.

---

Вариант без LINQ:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("temp"))
    Console.WriteLine($"{Path.GetFileName(file)} - {File.ReadAllText(file)}");
```

Что тут и как думаю вы уже догадались.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Оказывается все так просто было)